How to force turn off the Youtube video's subtitle via url
I’m following this thread because I also need to force the subtitles off for my YouTube video, but I haven’t had any luck.
I have try to use below, but the subtitle still showing
https://www.youtube.com/embed/TmJ7D3R7iIA?cc_load_policy=3&cc_lang_pref=en&autoplay=1
Can anybody help me, please?
Many thanks in advance.
Regards
Don

I suspect you can't turn off an important accessibility feature.
